# df -h /data/disk* shows extra information

Tags: linux, disk-usage, text-formatting

Red Hat. This is my output from `df -h /data/disk*` Why is /dev/mapper/vgroot-FS_root showing? This is only happening on one node. All nodes are identical (all have /dev/mapper/vgroot-FS_root)

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgroot-FS_root
                  1.5G  297M  1.1G  22% /
/dev/sda1             3.7T  947G  2.8T  26% /data/disk1
/dev/sdj1             3.7T  955G  2.8T  26% /data/disk10
/dev/sdk1             3.7T  942G  2.8T  26% /data/disk11
/dev/sdl1             3.7T  935G  2.8T  26% /data/disk12
/dev/sdb1             3.7T  939G  2.8T  26% /data/disk2
/dev/sdc1             3.7T  934G  2.8T  26% /data/disk3
/dev/sdd1             3.7T  949G  2.8T  26% /data/disk4
/dev/sde1             3.7T  932G  2.8T  26% /data/disk5
/dev/sdf1             3.7T  943G  2.8T  26% /data/disk6
/dev/sdg1             3.7T  944G  2.8T  26% /data/disk7
/dev/sdh1             3.7T  937G  2.8T  26% /data/disk8
/dev/sdi1             3.7T  944G  2.8T  26% /data/disk9
```

Here is the `df -h /data/disk*` on identical node

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       1.9T  782G  1.1T  42% /data/disk1
/dev/sdj1       1.9T  757G  1.1T  41% /data/disk10
/dev/sdk1       1.9T  805G  1.1T  44% /data/disk11
/dev/sdl1       1.9T  775G  1.1T  42% /data/disk12
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  791G  1.1T  43% /data/disk2
/dev/sdc1       1.9T  797G  1.1T  43% /data/disk3
/dev/sdd1       1.9T  780G  1.1T  42% /data/disk4
/dev/sde1       1.9T  802G  1.1T  44% /data/disk5
/dev/sdf1       1.9T  769G  1.1T  42% /data/disk6
/dev/sdg1       1.9T  788G  1.1T  43% /data/disk7
/dev/sdh1       1.9T  799G  1.1T  43% /data/disk8
/dev/sdi1       1.9T  778G  1.1T  42% /data/disk9
```

Comment: try running `echo /data/disk*` to see what it becomes - same on both nodes ?

Comment: I do see something out of place. The node in question has extra /data/disk with no number in it. Not sure if its related, im looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a `/data/disk` which is merely a directory.  Within the root filesystem itself.

So when queried with `df -h /data/disk` it merely displays the root filesystem's details.

Comment: Thanks, the node in question had empty directory /data/disk/ that other nodes did not have. Upon deleting the directory everything is working fine.

Comment: Great.  Worth marking this as answered then please?